# Configurable product not appearing in Catalogue (Magento 2.3.5)

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3.5-p1

I created the configurable product and sample product and linked them together using REST API. I can see the config product and the sample products and also the links correctly done in Admin mode. But when I view it as a user, I don't see the product. However, if I go into the configurable product (in admin mode) or one of the simple products and simply open it and save it (without making any changes), it appears. So what am I doing wrong?

Also I noticed that if I hard code the URL I can access the product, for example if I use the URL below I can access the product "test" and able to add it to the cart, but it does not appear in any of the categories and search results.

http://localhost:81/magento235/test.html

Comment: your run the reindex command ???

Comment: Once I run the reindexing it appears but I don't understand why the indexing is updated when the configurable product is created.

Answer (score 0):

Please run following commmand :

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Or you can also set "Index Management" under Admin > System > Tools > Index Management
and set option to "Update on Save".

Comment: Thanks Bhanu for you comment. You are on to something. All the indexes were already set to "Update On Save". I created the configurable product, simple product and the link using REST API and then ran the  "php bin/magento indexer:reindex" which you've suggested and the product appeared. Which means that the REST api call does not update the index? Is it a bug?

I noticed that this is only happening for configurable products. When I create a simple product using REST API it works fine and appears in the catalogue.